# Similarity of French and English languages !

Tags: anglais, apprentissage, comparaison-de-langues, éducation

If someone has dominance over English language usually in how much **period of time** can gain enough skill in **French language** ?

Since I believe **many words of English and French are similar** and just **slightly deformed** ?

Please **disabuse me** if I am wrong on this ! and give me more information about usually how English people study French ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Foreign Service Institute of the Department (FSI) of State estimates the time to learn French for native english speakers at *General Professional Proficiency* to 600 class hours.  See http://web.archive.org/web/20071014005901/http://www.nvtc.gov/lotw/months/november/learningExpectations.html which will give you more informations about their students and the learning conditions.

Comment: “It must be kept in mind that that students at FSI are almost 40 years old, are native speakers of English. and have a good aptitude for formal language study, plus knowledge of several other foreign languages. They study in small classes of no more than 6. Their schedule calls for 25 hours of class per week with 3-4 hours per day of directed self-study.”

Comment: @Laure please talk in English ?

Comment: @FereydoonShekofte Stéphane Gimenez's comment nicely says what I was referring to in my comment, the answer is only valid in those special conditions.